# dynamic width of angularjs xeditable.js textfield

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, x-editable

I am trying to make the width of  [xeditable textfield](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/25/)  increase or decrease with the input text. I tried the following code but no result.

```
    $('.editable-input').keyup(function() {
        $(this).css('width', $(this).val().length*10);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

After a long research, I found the solution of my problem. although it seemed that no one actually bothered my problem lol.

```
  $('.parent-container').on('keyup', '.editable-input', function () {
     $(this).css('width', $(this).val().length*9);   
  });
```

Comment: You should add a maximum limit.
`if ($(this).val().length*9 < 300)` then increase the width.